# DevOPS with Azure Data Factory

Tags: devops-services, azure-data-factory

I have created Azure Data Factory with Copy Activity using C# and Azure SDK.
How can deploy it using CI/CD ?

Any URL or link will help

Answer (score 1):

Data Factory continuous integration and delivery is now possible with directly through the web user interface using ARM Templates or even Git (Github or Azure DevOps).

Just click on "Set up Code Repository" and follow the steps.

Check the following link for more information, including a video demostration: https://aka.ms/azfr/401/02

Answer (score 0):

One idea that I got from Microsoft was that using the same Azure SDK you could deserialize the objects and save down the JSON files following the official directory structure into your local GitHub/Git working directory

[image: Official repository structure]

In other words you would have to mimic what the UI Save All/Save button does from the portal.

Then using Git bash, you can just commit and push to your working branch (i.e. develop) and from the UI you can just publish (this will create an adf_publish release branch with the ARM objects)

Official reference for CI using VSTS and the UI Publish feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, CI/CD for ADF is not very intuitive at first glance.
Check out this blog post where I'm describing what/how/why step by step:

[Deployment of Azure Data Factory with Azure DevOps](https://sqlplayer.net/2019/06/deployment-of-azure-data-factory-with-azure-devops/)

Let me know if you have any questions or concerns and finally - if that works for you.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

My resources on how to enable CI/CD using Azure DevOps and Data Factory comes from the Microsoft site below:

[Continuous integration and delivery (CI/CD) in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment)

I am still new to DevOps and CI/CD, but I do know that other departments had this set up and it looks to be working for them.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @csabinho I will keep that in mind next time I post.